# Custom adapter not displaying items in ListView

Tags: java, xml, listview

I am trying to display data in a ListView in a fragment however nothing appears, I can see that the data is correctly created in "chatLogList" but it seems like "notifyDataSetChanged()" doesn't trigger "GetView()" in the adapter.

**ChatFragment**

```
package com.example.cyberpunkredagent.ui.chats;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.example.cyberpunkredagent.ChatLog;
import com.example.cyberpunkredagent.ChatLogViewAdapter;
import com.example.cyberpunkredagent.ChatMessage;
import com.example.cyberpunkredagent.Home;
import com.example.cyberpunkredagent.R;
import com.example.cyberpunkredagent.databinding.FragmentChatsBinding;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;
    String username;

    ListView chatList;
    ArrayList<ChatLog> chatLogList;

    private FragmentChatsBinding binding;
    ChatLogViewAdapter adapter;
    DatabaseReference chatRef;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        username = ((Home)getActivity()).getUserName();
        ChatViewModel chatViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ChatViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentChatsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, null);

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        displayChatList();
    }

    public void displayChatList(){
        chatList = view.findViewById(R.id.list_of_chats);
        chatLogList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ChatLogViewAdapter(view.getContext(), chatLogList);

        chatRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats");
        chatRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> chats = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                for (DataSnapshot chat : chats) {
                    ArrayList<String> users = (ArrayList<String>) chat.child("users").getValue();
                    if (users.contains(username)){
                        ChatLog toAdd = new ChatLog(users, (ArrayList<ChatMessage>)chat.child("messages").getValue());
                        chatLogList.add(toAdd);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error Updating Database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        chatList.setAdapter(adapter);      
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

**ChatLogViewAdapter**

```
package com.example.cyberpunkredagent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChatLogViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChatLog> {
    public ChatLogViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ChatLog> chatLogList){
        super(context, 0, chatLogList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ChatLog chatLog = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_log_preview, parent, false);
        }
        TextView messageText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        TextView messageUser = convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
        TextView messageTime = convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

        messageText.setText(chatLog.lastMessageText());
        messageUser.setText(chatLog.chatUserString());
        // Format the date before showing it
        messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                chatLog.lastMessageTime()));
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**chat_log_preview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/message_user"
        android:text="Name" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/message_time"
        android:text="Time"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:text="Message"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have looked through similar questions but most of them revolve around a problem with redefining the list given to the adapter which I don't think I am doing.

I know the data is being added and that "notifyDataSetChanged()" is being called. I just can't get the adapter to populate the listview, and it appears that it is because it never calls "getView()" in the adapter